# Expose a child object's VF Page in Parent Object's Page Layout

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my data model.

Master Object  : Expense

Detail Object : ExpenseChild

[image]

The above picture shows the page layout that I currently have.

Can someone let me know whether it is feasible to show my own ExpenseChild VF page instead of the related list ( bordered in blue ) ?.

UPDATE :

@Tx Knolle !.
I am currently following what you have mentioned.

Using Parent Object's controller + extensions, I was able to pull the child records's data.

My code (which is at a very nascent stage as of now) is as below

```
VF Markup

<apex:page standardController="Expense__c" extensions="test_e" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
 <h1> ExpenseChild's CLText Field Content : </h1>
  <br/>
  <h2> {!s} </h2>
</apex:page>

Controller

public class test_e {

public String s;
public String child_data;

public String gets()
{

return child_data;
}


    public test_e(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

     s = String.valueOf(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
     List<ExpenseChild__c> child_coll = [SELECT Id,CLText__c FROM ExpenseChild__c WHERE Expense__c = :s];
     //child_data = String.ValueOf(child_coll.size());

     for(ExpenseChild__c ec : child_coll)
     {
          if(child_data != null)
          {
          child_data = child_data+ec.CLText__c.left(10)+'\n\n';
          }
          else
          {
           child_data = ec.CLText__c.left(10);
           }

     }

    }
```

}

Screenshot as of now :

[image]

**Can you tell me is it possible to display the child records in the form of a table ?.**

Tx for the help !

Comment: You can do this without code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there is no way to achieve that exact behavior, because it is required that an [embedded VF page in a page layout use a standardController for that entity](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US).  You can still get the data onto the parent VF page, though, and with some refactoring make it a bit more maintainable.

Here's an idea that you could use.

1. Refactor the child VF page so that its entire body is in a Visualforce component.
2. Create a VF page with the parent standardController specified.
3. Add the component to the parent page.
4. [Embed the parent Visualforce page in the page layout](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US).

You can use an [apex:pageBlockTable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) to display the records in a table.

You may need to tinker around with how the component should work (e.g., processes a list of children vs. one child), but in the end you'd have a single place, the component, that would need to be maintained.  Changes to it would be seen on the parent page layout and on the child's VF page.

Comment: Hi Knolle..I have updated my question after following your inputs..can you please take a look ?..tx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. The important thing is to make certain there's an easy means of ensuring your new records will be linked to a Master Record. A good example of how to do this is in the [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/) in the Managing Review Assessments section where there's a M-D relationship between the Job Application and the Review that references the title of the position on the Review's parent object job application record via a cross-object formula hyperlink.

Comment: Tx..I will go through the link you have mentioned..appreciate it :)